# Безопасно ли так писать PHP класс?

Tags: php

Пример класса:

```
class Page
{
    private $var1;
    /**
     * конструктор класса
     * */
    public function __construct($say = 'its work??')
    {
        $this->var1 = $say;
    }

    /**
     * деструктор класса
     * */
    public function __destruct()
    {}

    /**
     * Метод вывода страницы
     * */
    public function GetHtmlPage()
    {
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
        <html>
        <head>
          <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">

          <title></title>

        </head>
        <body>
        <h1><?php echo $this->var1;?></h1>
        </body>
        </html>
        <?php
    }

}
```

Comment: а в чем вы здесь небезопастность видете?

Comment: $page = new Page('<script>alert(/xss/)</script>'); < это мне понятно, как бы я в курсе что данные надо обрабатывать что бы туда не лезло абы что. Но я имел ввиду, можно ли оформить метод именно в таком стиле как показано в public "function GetHtmlPage()", а не как скажем: 
$html .= '<html>';
$html .= '<head>';
$html .= '<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">';
$html .= '</head>';
$html .= '<body>';
$html .= '</body>';
$html .= '</html>';
return $html;
или тоже самое но через echo('');
Просто нельзя ли будет обратится к файлу где лежит класс и получить html метода?

Comment: Я сейчас не совсем понял о чем речь. Но, если в файле класса не вызывается GetHtmlPage() никакого html вы не получите, если хотите можно запретить доступ файлу класса из вне, инициализировав например константу в главном файле, а потом сделав проверку на ее существование в классе, и если ее нет то убивать скрипт через die().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Возможна xss, если есть возможность управлять входящими данными и при вызове данные не обрабатываются через htmlspecialchars

Comment: что? xss? ГДЕ!!!???

Comment: $page = new Page('<script>alert(/xss/)</script>');
echo $page->GetHtmlPage();

это ли не xss ?

Comment: ничего глупее не слышал :)))))

Comment: Тогда советую прочитать что такое xss, перечитать еще раз мой ответ и попробовать те пару строчек что я написал выше.

Comment: ок. я создаю такую страницу, ты засунешь туда свой xss???

Comment: Теперь перечитай мой первый ответ на вопрос, там уже есть ответ на твой вопрос.

Comment: Здесь однозначно есть уязвимость XSS рода!

Comment: Ололо, а что если данные, которые передаются конструктору - уже отфильтрованные данные в БД?(и ничто иное)

Ога и `sql injection` тут есть, это 100% просто, нет ни одного запроса к БД, но зато injection есть...

Как по мне очевидно - автора интересовала необычная запись метода `GetHtmlPage`, но никак не то, о чем пишите вы.

Высосали проблему из пальца и философствуете тут :)

Answer (score 0):

И правда, если инициализация переменной $var1:

```
public function __construct($say = 'its work??')
    {
        $this->var1 = $say;
    }
```

производится строкой, полученной от пользователя( POST`ом или Get`ом ), то появляется 100% уязвимость, позволяющая произвести XSS в методе GetHTMLPage() в строчке:

```
<h1><?php echo $this->var1;?></h1>
```

Не знаю, как вы фильтруете данные, но, как видно из вашего( надеюсь, псевдокода ) кода - никак! Это очень опасно! А если переменная $var1 используется где-нибудь в Выполнении SQL запроса, то вытекает вторая потенциальная уязвимость - SQL Injection!

---

**Будьте внимательнее!**